# git branch is behind master for too many commits -- most efficient way to rebase?

Tags: git, git-branch, git-rebase

when I do `git rebase master`, I have to resolve conflicts against every single commit I was behind of. it's a pain.

Is there a way to do it the SVN style -- I only compare against the latest snapshot, then resolve the conflict once and for good.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The maybe easiest approach would be to simply merge `master` into the branch in question. This will obviously only ask once for conflict resolution.

Alternativly if you always have to handle the same conflicts over and over, you can take a look at [`git rerere` (reuse recorded resolution)](https://git-scm.com/book/en/v2/Git-Tools-Rerere); as the name suggests it records the resolutions you apply to a conflict and will resolve such conflicts automatically in the future.

Comment: but I need to make sure my change is on top of the master commits tho

Comment: @CodeNoob Then take a look at `git rerere` as I suggested.

Comment: New page with "rerere" description is here: https://git-scm.com/book/en/v2/Git-Tools-Rerere